# A question at stackoverflow triggered my AVG anti-virus

Tags: support, virus

I have no idea why, first time I see that thing happens on SE network, question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510245/code-injection-what-could-be-the-security-leak

Picture:

[image]

Comment: It's almost certainly just being overly sensitive.

Comment: @Servy, well... I can't see the content so I can't tell... what is in that question?

Comment: Probably the antivirus just look for "#8f4d8e#" on web page and when found it think it's a virus... (now this page will also be a "virus")

Comment: It looks like it has a malicious script posted as code, so it wouldn't be harmful to your system to view the page (unless you explicitly copied the code to the console and executed it) but it's at least understandable that AVG would try to protect you from this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It could be looking at any number of sections of that script,I know that's not what I'd choose as a likely pattern to match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question (now deleted) contained a copy-paste of some exploit code that a user found on his website. The exploit code matches the [Blackhole Exploit Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_exploit_kit), which AVG detected as a threat (which it technically is, though it is inert as a StackOverflow question).

The kit's JavaScript components are legitimately malicious if inserted on an HTML page, so AVG isn't necessarily wrong in the detection -- it can't be expected to tell whether malicious code is being safely handled in a `<pre>` block or not.

Comment: For those interested, here's the script that triggered the antivirus: http://pastebin.com/964UNjem (just don't run the code!)